# Wireshark not showing http protocols

Tags: http, wireshark, pcap

I an new to Wireshark.
I folowed [this](https://opensourceforu.com/2017/10/visualising-response-time-web-server-using-wireshark/) tutorial which simply pings www.wikipedia.org and captures packets using Wireshark.
As per this tutorials, wireshark captures http packets.
But, for some reasons it not showing packets under http protocol, instead I have TLSv1.2 packets. 
Note: I also have promiscuous mode on.
I need to see http packets so as to view the request and response.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia as most modern sites has redirect from HTTP to HTTPS protocol. So when you send HTTP request to it you’ll receive answer with 304 redirect to HTTPS in it. After that all communication will go through HTTPS. And HTTPS traffic is encrypted with TLS.

Answer (score 0):

`ping` does not use HTTP, it uses ICMP, which is a completely different protocol. You would not see any HTTP packets if you ping www.wikipedia.org, you would only see ICMP packets. More precisely, you would see ICMP Type 8 Messages (Echo Request) going to www.wikipedia.org and ICMP Type 0 Messages (Echo Reply) coming back from www.wikipedia.org.

Also, Wikipedia, like most modern websites, does not use HTTP anymore but only HTTPS, so you wouldn't see HTTP traffic anyway, only HTTPS.